# How to specify ticks formatter for several subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to specify ticks formatter for each plot of several subplots:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker


x = np.arange(10)
y = x

fig = plt.figure()

for i in [1, 2, 3]:
    ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 1, i)
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ticks = ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{}:{:g}'.format(i, x))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticks)

plt.show()
```

But only the last (bottom) fotmatter is used for all other plots. What I do wrong?
[image: output example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`ticker.FormatStrFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter) object as shown below.

I believe the problem with your original approach was that you were setting the `Formatter` for each axis to the `tick` variable and then overwriting it on the next iteration, as such all your graphs were using the `tick` variable from the last iteration.

When you create `Formatter` objects you have to have one for each subplot, in my code below it's not a problem because I don't assign the `FormatStrFormatter` to a variable.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = np.arange(10)
y = x

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('{}:%d'.format(i+1)))

plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]

#### EDIT

Here is a version which uses the original `FuncFormatter` formatter object. The `map` method creates three separate ticker objects from their associated lambda functions. The `for` loop iterates over both `ax` and `tick` to assign each subplot.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

x = np.arange(10)
y = x

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1)

def create_ticker(i):
    # Create a FuncFormatter.
    return ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '{}:{:g}'.format(i+1, x))

ticks = map(create_ticker, range(3))

for ax, tick in zip(axes, ticks):
    ax.plot(x, y)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(tick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I need to do more complex job in formatter subroutine. Not just format number. Your point with overwriting looks promising. When I use separate variable for each plot it works. Bud I do not understand it.